# AngularFire2 and Ionic2, calculating list sum

Tags: list, loops, ionic2, angularfire2

please help me to figure out how to calculate a sum of objects values coming from firebase using AngularFire2 in ionic.

I am trying do this way:

in the HTML file i want call the function:

```
    <ion-col col-1>
      {{(calculateAverage(student.$key) | async)}}
    </ion-col>
```

In the .ts file i want to do something like this, get the list of objects, iterate over it and sum the values of a child and return that value to the html.

i know how to use `this.af.database.list` to get a list and show values in the HTML using the *ngFor, but not know how to iterate in the .ts file and return a value to the HTML, cause this is async.

Example of firebase data:

`"-KhdUCJAyr7Y4Zz3QOnl" : {
    "-KigSgGlWyFQao80DuA0" : {
      "value" : "30"
    },
    "-KigTDI3Nue88If0fdYl" : {
      "value" : "70"
    }
  }`

Can anyong help me please?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the calculate in `subscribe` of `this.af.database.list`.

```
// suppose you keep the observable
this.items = this.af.database.list('/sample');

// do calculate in observable.subscribe
this.items.subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(item => {
    // sum here
    calculateSum(item.value);
  });
  // calculate average here
  calculateAverage();
});
```

---

example of how to calculate and show in templete:

```
sumValue = 0;
averageValue = 0;
// sum values
calculateSum(value) {
  this.sumValue = this.sumValue + parseInt(value);
}
calculateAverage(count) {
  this.averageValue = this.sumValue / count;
}
```

display result of calculate in template:

```
<span>averageValue</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but how i do the return in an async function?

Comment: @JorgeVieira you can't return from asyn function, but do what you want with its callback.

Comment: I'm sorry, cause i am new with ionic/angular. Can you show me for example how to use the result of the sum in the html, please?

Comment: @JorgeVieira I gave update the answer for including an example.

Comment: Oh thank you @Pengyy. I will try here and see if works.

Comment: this is perfect answer :)